# How can I add files in new directories with maven scm:add command in subversion?

Tags: java, svn, maven

I have the following (simplified) folder structure:

```
pom.xml (with correct scm)
src/folder1
src/folder2
```

*folder1* and *folder2* each conatain a test.txt file. *folder1* is already committed, *folder2* is not yet under version control.

What I try to do is to add the file *src/folder2/test.txt* to version control.

If I execute

```
mvn scm:add -Dbasedir=${project.basedir}/src -Dincludes=**/folder2/*
```

I get this message:

```
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: 'src/folder2' is not a working copy
```

Because the pattern **/folder2/* does not include folders I tried to add the folder first:

```
mvn scm:add -Dbasedir=${project.basedir}/src -Dincludes=**/folder2/
```

Same error message. With

```
mvn scm:add -Dbasedir=${project.basedir}/src -Dincludes=**/folder2
```

(i.e. without trailing slash) I got the message

"Exception while executing SCM command. You must provide at least one file/directory to add"

Same with *-Dincludes=folder2, -Dincludes=folder2/* or even when I drop "includes" entirely.

How do I get the maven-scm-plugin to add the folder first before it tries to add the files in the new directory?

I have tested this with Maven 2.2.1 and Maven 3.0.4 with scm-Plugin Versions 1.4 (the actual version in our project) and 1.6 (the latest version).

Comment: Have you tried `mvn scm:add -Dbasedir=${project.basedir} -Dincludes=**src/folder2/*`?

Comment: Same result. basedir=${project.basedir} is the default, so removing this option is the same, too.

Comment: Oh, and I have tested this with Maven 2.2.1 and Maven 3.0.4 with scm-Plugin Versions 1.4 (the actual version in our project) and 1.6 (the latest version)... (Added this to the question.)

Comment: No, I have worked around this with other tools...

Answer (score 2):

I have this working with your configuration:

```
pom.xml (with correct scm) <- .git folder
src/folder1 <- under scm
src/folder2 (text1.txt) <- not under scm
```

Git project before command:
[image]

### Solution

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.12.0:add -Dbasedir=${project.basedir} -Dincludes=**/folder2/
```

### Result

[image]

[image]